# Process zip file Azure function that runs as isolated process

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I want to create an Azure function that triggers when a zip file is uploaded to an Azure storage account. I need to create this function as an isolated process because I'm targeting .NET 7 which cannot run in-process.
But the isolated process doesn't support blob stream input, the blob content comes in as a string. I've tried to convert the string to a MemoryStream using GetBytes from several encodings (UTF8, ASCII, etc.) but I can't get a valid ZipArchive from it. The file that I'm testing with works fine if I just open it as a filestream from disk.

So my question basically is, if it's just not possible to process a zip file from an isolated process Azure function, or if there is something I'm doing wrong?

Some code:

```
    public void Run([BlobTrigger("test-zip/{name}", Connection = "StorageConnectionString")] string myBlob, string name)
    {
        var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(myBlob);
        using var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
        using var zip = new ZipArchive(ms); // exception or invalid zip (no entries) depending on the encoding that is used
    }

string blob = @"C:\tmp\test.zip";
using var file = File.OpenRead(blob);
using var zip = new ZipArchive(file); // works fine
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you are not doing anything wrong. It *will* be possible to use a stream as input type but not at the moment since it is in preview.

If you are comfortable using preview features read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob?pivots=programming-language-csharp&tabs=isolated-process%2Cextensionv5%2Cextensionv3#binding-types):

> Preview types require use of Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Storage.Blobs 5.1.0-preview1 or later, Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker 1.12.1-preview1 or later, and Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk 1.9.0-preview1 or later. When developing on your local machine, you will need Azure Functions Core Tools version 4.0.5000 or later.

Comment: Thanks, I first tried to use Stream instead of string with the preview package, but it was basically giving the same error as when I tried to convert the string to stream. But then I tried byte[] instead, and that works, even with the latest non-preview version 5.0.1! But I also installed the Azure Functions Core Tools, so now I am not sure if that was also a required step or not ..

Comment: @Hanno could be but I don't know for sure either.